# How can I make user info card via pure FlexBox

Tags: css, flexbox

This is my design:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aWCV.png)

How can I make it using Flexbox?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the cleanest one, but at least it works using flexbox!

The styling:

```
.container {
        display: flex;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        width: 340px;
        padding: 3px;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .secondary-container:nth-child(1) {
        color: rgb(165, 165, 165);
    }
    .secondary-container:nth-child(2) {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        align-self: center;
    }
```

The HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="secondary-container">
        <p>User ID:</p>
        <p>Email:</p>
        <p>Country:</p>
        <p>Device ID:</p>
        <p>Registered:</p>
        <p>Last Updated:</p>
    </span>
    <span class="secondary-container">
        <p>339754133048101</p>
        <p>kelly.walkingshaw@gmail.com</p>
        <p>Armenia</p>
        <p>d16bc5be-02c2-4f82-81</p>
        <p>2016-11-03 / 21:26</p>
        <p>2020-09-03 / 11:58</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Good luck on your project! ~E

Answer (score 0):

While flexbox is a great modern way to create layouts, it doesn't make sense in this case. You would be adding unnecessary styling. You can easily do this with a table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        table, tr {
            width: 500px
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you must use flexbox, try the following. If you don't need to specify the width of the items yourself, a good idea is to use `flex-grow: 1` instead of `width:50%`. This resizes it to fit the container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        table, tr {
            width: 500px
        }

        table > tr > td{
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:500px;">
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
            <div style="width: 50%">1</div>
            <div style="width: 50%">2</div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
            <div style="width: 50%">1</div>
            <div style="width: 50%">2</div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
            <div style="width: 50%">1</div>
            <div style="width: 50%">2</div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
            <div style="width: 50%">1</div>
            <div style="width: 50%">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```